# Computation of dependencies (related to the K prelude)

Tags: kframework

I'm particularly interested to understand the K prelude (how it is structured, why its content is like that, how "kompile" calculates dependencies, etc).
The main question is: what is the criterion for a hooked symbol from the K prelude to be copied into the generated Kore file?

Here some examples of potential problems:

1. The symbol **andBool** is copied with its associated rewrite rules, which does not seem to be the case for the symbol **in_keys**, which is simply copied without its rewrite rules.
   Other symbols seem to be useless (for the IMP semantic) but exist, with or without its rewrite rules, in the generated Kore file, such as **countAllOccurrences**, **findChar**, **signExtendBitRangeInt** or **Float2String**.
2. It seems that **SortId** is generated by the line `syntax Id [token]`. However, the lines `"syntax Bool ::= "true" [token]` and `syntax Bool ::= "false" [token]` do not generate **true** and **false** symbols.
   (Moreover, is it a choice that **true** and **false** are values and not constructors?)
3. The sort named **SortId** is not generated for the following example, whereas some generated hooked symbols depend on this sort. This problem does not exist with the IMP semantic.

```
module MAX-OW-SYNTAX
    imports INT
    imports BOOL
    syntax Exp ::= Int | "(" Exp ")" [bracket]
                 | "max" Exp Exp
endmodule
        
module MAX-OW
    imports MAX-OW-SYNTAX
    syntax KResult ::= Int
        
    rule max X Y => Y requires X <Int Y
    rule max X _ => X [owise]
endmodule
```

4. Is it correct that the K prelude is implemented in each language of each backend, and that an implementation in the Kore language is available in the K prelude?
   Do you have the necessary interface to implement for a new backend? (For instance, `Bag` is obsolete, but not `Set`, `List` and `Map`, but I don't know the list of set operators, map operators, etc. that the new backend must provide.)
5. Is there a reason why **andThenBool** and **andBool** have the same semantics once implemented in the Kore syntax (Booleans module)?
6. Where are the rewrite rules defined for **==Bool**, used in the definition of **=/=Bool** (Booleans module)?

Answer (score 1):

The best reference point for the K internals is the [User Manual](https://github.com/runtimeverification/k/blob/master/USER_MANUAL.md), along with the [K source for the prelude](https://github.com/runtimeverification/k/blob/master/k-distribution/include/kframework/builtin/domains.md). To respond to your specific questions as best as I can:

1. `in_keys` only has [simplification rules](https://github.com/runtimeverification/k/blob/master/k-distribution/include/kframework/builtin/domains.md#implementation-of-maps) that apply on symbolic backends. These will not apply on concrete backends, and so those backends use the hooked implementation `MAP.in_keys`. Some functions (such as `andBool`) can be implemented both in K and as an efficient backend hook. For example, on the K LLVM backend, `andBool` is implemented by [code generation](https://github.com/runtimeverification/llvm-backend/blob/e5f00754b00ed17d98472f5a90d034a1d4b82c04/lib/codegen/CreateTerm.cpp#L283). If a backend didn't support that hook, the (relatively) inefficient K rewriting implementation would be used.
2. The `Id` sort is [built in](https://github.com/runtimeverification/llvm-backend/blob/e5f00754b00ed17d98472f5a90d034a1d4b82c04/lib/codegen/CreateTerm.cpp#L283) for convenience. It represents program identifiers.
3. You haven't imported `DOMAINS` in this example. Doing so will pull in the `Id` sort and related rewrites.
4. *Very* roughly, and largely [for internal purposes](https://github.com/runtimeverification/k/blob/master/USER_MANUAL.md#pending-documentation). Do you have a hypothetical K backend in mind, or is there a way in which the LLVM / Haskell backends provided by K are inadequate for your specific use case?
5. `andThenBool` is *required* to short-circuit its arguments; `andBool` is *permitted* to short-circuit, but may evaluate both arguments strictly. An implementation that makes both perform short-circuiting is valid.
6. `==Bool` is implemented only in terms of [a hook](https://github.com/runtimeverification/llvm-backend/blob/master/runtime/equality.ll). In `domains.md`, you can see the `hook(BOOL.eq)` attribute that indicates how `==Bool` is implemented.

Do let us know if you have further questions, or would like help implementing a specific semantics in K.

Comment: One comment about `andBool` vs `andThenBool`. On symbolic backends, it's possible that the arguments to `andBool` and `andThenBool` are _undefined_, that is, an assignment to the variables present in their arguments could lead to one of the arguments not being `true` or `false`. In this case, the _entire_ term is undefined, regardless of which argument the undefinedness comes from and whether the implementation is short-circuiting or not. This is just a property of Matching Logic functions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer:

 1.  OK, but why are the symbols countAllOccurrences, findChar, signExtendBitRangeInt or Float2String in the generated Kore file for the IMP semantic?

Comment: 2. Yes, but is it the case for true and false too?

Comment: 3. The previous semantic is accepted by K. For me, there is a bug because some generated hooked symbols depend on the sort Id, but Id isn't generated.

Comment: 4. Yes, I'm developing the translator from K to Dedukti, but I don't understand how the K prelude is used in a K semantic.

Comment: 5. OK, great! Thanks.

Comment: 6. OK, great! Do you have the exhaustive list of hooks?